# Is this a real Star Trek episode?

Tags: breaking-bad, star-trek

In the *Breaking Bad* episode ["Blood Money"](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Blood_Money), there is a reference to an episode of *Star Trek* in which Chekhov is killed because his stomach is in space.

Is this a real episode of *Star Trek*?

Comment: You know, once me and another couple guys during lunch in high school managed to list all 79 episodes from the original series. It sure was not easy and each of us made major contributions -- maybe someone would only remember enough to serve as a hint so we could remember the entire episode -- and I doubt now, 40 years later, I could be much help, too far removed from time when I watched reruns. But I would have known instantly that this was a fake episode and how could you not know this??

Answer (score 10):

How do you confuse a scenario that is clearly [the invention of a character](https://www.wired.com/2013/08/breaking-bad-star-trek-script/) with a real episode?

> Following Pete's speculation that the transporter on the Enterprise essentially killed and then created a "color Xerox" of everyone it beamed up or out, **Badger launches into his greatest monologue of the series: a detailed description of his own (hilarious) screenplay about *Star Trek: The Original Series* pie-eating contest**, albeit it one that gets a few Trek details wrong.
>
> It essentially lays out a scenario in which Chekov is winning the Enterprise crew pie-eating contest by having Scotty beam the pies out of his stomach as he eats them, and ends with Scotty getting so distracted by the attractive Uhura that he ends up beaming more than just the pies out of Chekov. Sayeth Badger: "Chekov screams, he sprays blood out of his mouth – Scotty beamed his guts into space!"

Badger literally starts of with:

> I ever tell you about **my *Star Trek* script**? *Star Trek* script? Yeah. I gotta write it down is all.

Comment: Jeez, having only watched Breaking Bad once during its original run, I totally forgot about this amazingly hilarious scene. As stupid as the question was, it still gets an upvote from me for allowing this amazing answer and reminder that currently has me in stitches for the first time since seeing it performed.